# How to create common functions in Python?

Tags: python

I want to put a common function in a base module, but the common function calls a specific function declared in two different modules.
And I do not want to use classes, just modules and functions.

Why does this not work?

- `base_module.py`:

  ```
  def toto():
    tutu()
  ```
- `module1.py`:

  ```
  from base_module import toto
  def tutu():
    print('hello')
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    toto()
  ```
- `module2.py`:

  ```
  from base_module import toto
  def tutu():
    print('world')
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    toto()
  ```

Comment: base_module.py doesn't know what is tutu. what you can do is make toto accept a function as a parameter, then inside your module1 and module2 you can call toto passing the function tutu as a parameter `toto(tutu)`

Comment: As you've shown, you have two different `tutu` functions, how is the base module supposed to know which its supposed to call?

Comment: Namespaces need to be unambiguous. Let's say you've got module3.py that imports both module1 and module2. What should `toto` do in this case? What should it do if you import it in a module that doesn't implement `tutu`?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is called dependency injection. Ideally/best practice would be to use classes and define "interface". But without classes, you can just pass the `tutu` function to your `toto` function:

base_module.py:

```
def toto(tutu_func):
  tutu_func()
```

module1.py:

```
from base_module import toto
def tutu():
  print('hello')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  toto(tutu_func=tutu)
```

module2.py

```
from base_module import toto
def tutu():
  print('world')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  toto(tutu_func=tutu)
```

---

You can also define the default `tutu`:

base_module.py:

```
def default_tutu():
    print("!!!")

def toto(tutu_func=default_tutu):
  tutu_func()
```